# dynamic table name in cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to insert data whose schema is dynamic, as in user enters the schema name. For some reason I get `ORA-000942: table doesn't exist` even though table is there in the correct schema.

Here is the code:

```
declare
  l_ext_files_names varchar2(4000) := '&1';
  l_schema_name varchar2(4000) := '&2';
  l_table_name varchar2(4000) := l_schema_name||'.files_tbl';
  l_int_files_names varchar2(4000);
  c_file_name sys_refcursor;
begin
  open c_file_name for 'select file_names from '||l_table_name;
  loop
     fetch c_file_name into l_int_files_names;
     if (l_int_files_names <> l_ext_files_names) then
        insert into l_table_name (file_names, status)
        values (l_files_names, 'done');
     end if;
  end loop;
  close c_file_name;
end;
```

Any idea where I am making the mistake?
Cheers in advance :)

Comment: It could be privilege issue.

Comment: Thank for for replies. I tried insert statement using the same schema that created the table. The insert statement went fine. So the problem is not with privileges.

Comment: try the select statement with the same user and `set role NONE;` If the SELECT privilge is granted via ROLE it will not work in PL/SQL.

Comment: Hi, yes the select statement works with set role NONE;

Comment: What do you get when you insert `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('select file_names from '||l_table_name);` before you open the cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches and strolling trough the internet, this is what I found. It seems that I need to declare the schema and table names variables in a slightly different way. Why this solution works? no idea.

```
declare
  l_schema_name all_tables.owner%type := '&1';
  l_ext_files_names varchar2(4000) := '&2';
  l_table_name all_tables.table_name%type := 'FILES_TBL';
  l_int_files_names varchar2(4000);
  c_file_name sys_refcursor; 

begin
  open c_file_name for 'select file_names from '||l_schema_name||'.'||l_table_name;
  fetch c_file_name into l_int_files_names;
  if c_file_name%notfound then
     execute immediate 'insert into '||l_schema_name||'.'||l_table_name||' (file_names, entry, status) values ('''||l_ext_files_names||''', sysdate, ''done'')';
     commit;
  elsif (l_int_files_names <> l_ext_files_names) then
     execute immediate 'insert into '||l_schema_name||'.'||l_table_name||' (file_names, entry, status) values ('''||l_ext_files_names||''', sysdate, ''done'')';
     commit;
  else 
     dbms_output.put_line ('Already there.');
  end if;
exception when others then
  dbms_output.put_line ('Some errors.');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the `user` doesn't have the `privilege` to access the table in **other schema**.

You would need to grant the `SELECT` privilege.

```
GRANT SELECT ON table_name TO username;
```

Put the required `table_name` and in `username` put the user which is executing the **SELECT**.