# Oracle: Dynamic table name for a bulk collect cursor in stored procedure

Tags: oracle11g

I am developing a stored procedure with a cursor of bulk collect.
I initially developed a static cursor with bulk collect as below:

```
procedure p_get_x ( p_x  in NUMBER )
    is
      l_var1 is number;
      cursor c_x is
      select 
        col1, col2
        from tbl1
      where col1 = l_var1
      ;
      t_x c_x%rowtype; 
      TYPE tab_x IS TABLE OF t_x%TYPE;
      tb_x tab_x; 

    BEGIN      
             open c_x;
             fetch c_x bulk collect into tb_x ;
             close c_x
           ;
          for idx in 1 .. tb_x.count 
            loop
              insert into tbl2
               (
                col1,
                col2
               )
               values (
               tb_x(idx).col1,
               tb_x(idx).col2
               );
          end loop;
          commit;
      end if;    
end p_get_x;
```

The requirement is to create a generic procedure.
Based on input - p_x, the procedure have to execute different cursor definition, but only 1 cursor in an execution.
The cursor table name will be different and each table will have some common column names and few specific column names.
example :- table a - col1, col2 ,col3 
           table b - col1, col3, col4

How to create a dynamic cursor wilt bulk collect as on average there would be 5 Million rows in that table?

References I tried:
[Dynamic Variable in Cursor in Oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722277/dynamic-variable-in-cursor-in-oracle-stored-procedure)
[dynamic table name in cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182880/dynamic-table-name-in-cursor)

Thanks

Comment: Are there really only two options?  If so, you're going to be much better off with a simple `IF` statement that branches to one of two paths each using static SQL than trying to resort to dynamic SQL.

Comment: if statement does not work in declare statement

Comment: Is it possible to have ref cursor and bulk binding together? I am using Oracle 18

Comment: I'm suggesting that you declare two different cursors (assuming you want to use explicit cursors) and have an `IF` statement in the body of your procedure that processes one or the other depending on the input.

Comment: can you give reference please

Answer (score 1):

If there are really only two paths, it likely doesn't make sense to resort to dynamic SQL.  Use static SQL and just add branching logic to your code.  Something like

```
create or replace procedure do_something( p_table_name in varchar2 )
as
  type t1_tbl is table of t1%rowtype;
  type t2_tbl is table of t2%rowtype;

  l_t1s t1_tbl;
  l_t2s t2_tbl;
begin
  if( p_table_name = 'T1' )
  then
    select *
      bulk collect into l_t1s
      from t1;

    forall i in 1 .. l_t1s.count
      insert into dest_table( columns )
        values( l_t1s(i).col1, ... l_t1s(i).colN );
  elsif( p_table_name = 'T2' )
  then
    select *
      bulk collect into l_t2s
      from t2;

    forall i in 1 .. l_t2s.count
      insert into dest_table( columns )
        values( l_t2s(i).colA, ... l_t2s(i).colN );
  end if;
end;
```